# Troube solving integration by substitution property

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble solving the following problem from Apostol (Section 5.8, Question 25, Page 217):
*If $m$ is a positive integer, show that
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{m} x \sin^{m} x dx = 2^{-m} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{m} x dx
$$*

My thinking has been to approach this by consider when $m$ is odd and when $m$ is even. Since this section related to Integration by substitution, I was taking this approach.

When I considered $m$ as odd, I took the substitution $u = \cos x$, $du = -\sin x dx$ and this took me down the following path: 
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^mx \sin^mx dx = -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^m x \sin^{m-1} x(-\sin x) dx
$$
$$
= -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^mx (\sin^2 x)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}(-\sin x) dx
$$
$$
= -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^mx (1 - \cos^2 x)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}(-\sin x) dx
$$
$$
= -\int_1^0u^m(1 - u^2)^{\frac{m-1}{2}} du
$$
$$
= \int_0^1u^m(1 - u^2)^{\frac{m-1}{2}} du
$$
$$
= \int_0^1u^m \Sigma_{k = 0}^{\frac{m-1}{2}} {{\frac{m-1}{2}} \choose k} (-1)^k u^{2k} du
$$
It was at this point that I'm thinking "???" because it seemed as if I was heading away from the answer and not towards the answer. I have not attempted to tackle the case when $m$ is even because I feel this would be MUCH more confusing.

If anyone can give me a better hint to take which would cast some light on this problem of mine that would be appreciated.

Comment: Wow, a most comprehensive answer! I was only expecting some hints. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\cos^m x \sin^m x=(\cos x \sin x)^m=2^{-m}\sin^m (2x)$.

Let $t=2x$. $x=\frac12t$, and $dx=\frac12dt$.

$$I(m)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}dx\,\cos^m{x}\sin^m{x}=2^{-m}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}dx\,\sin^m{2x}\\
=2^{-m}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac12dt\,\sin^m{t}$$

Next, let $u=t-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $t=u+\frac{\pi}{2}$.

$$I(m)=2^{-m}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac12dt\,\sin^m{t}\\
=2^{-m}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac12du\,\sin^m{(u+\frac{\pi}{2})}\\
=2^{-m}\frac12\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}du\,\cos^m{u}\\
=2^{-m}\frac12\cdot 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}du\,\cos^m{u}\\
=2^{-m}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}du\,\cos^m{u}.$$ *Little Box*